# How can we compute the Fréchet derivative of $q\mapsto\int\frac{(pf)^2}q\:{\rm d}\lambda$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda=1$$
- $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$

> Now let $$\Phi(q):=\int_{\left\{\:q\:>\:0\:\right\}}\frac{(pf)^2}q\:{\rm d}\lambda$$ for $q\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ with $q\ge0$. Are we able to rigorously prove that the Fréchet derivative of $\Phi$ exists and is equal to $-\frac{(pf)^2}{q^2}$?

My first problem is a formal one: A mapping can only be Fréchet derivative on an open subset of a Banach space. We would clearly want to consider the Banach space $L^1(\lambda)$, but how do we need to define the open suset $\Omega$?

If this question is clarified, we should need to show $$\frac{\left|\Phi(q+h)-\Phi(q)+\frac{(pf)^2}{h^2}\right|}{\left\|h\right\|_{L^1(\lambda)}}\xrightarrow{h\to0}0\tag1$$ for all $q\in\Omega$. How can we do this? (If at all.)

Please take note of my related question: [Minimize $q\mapsto\int\frac{(pf)^2}q\:{\rm d}\lambda$ subject to $\int q\:{\rm }\lambda=1$ using the method of Lagrange multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3313495/47771).

Comment: @s.harp Yes, $\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ is the semi-normed space of $\mathcal E$-measurable $g:E\to\mathbb R$ with $\int|g|\:{\rm d}\lambda<\infty$ and $L^1(\lambda)$ is the usual quotient space obtained by identifying almost everywhere equal functions.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not rigorous, but provides a first insight into why this should be the correct derivative:

Note that for $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ you obtain (Taylor series)
$$
g(x+h) = g(x) + g'(x)h = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{h}{x^2} + o(|h|)
$$
Therefore, $\frac{1}{q+h}$ has the following linear approximation (for small $h$):
$$
\frac{1}{q+h} \approx \frac{1}{q} - \frac{h}{q^2},
$$
which implies
$$
\Phi(q+h)
=
\int \frac{(pf)^2}{q+h}\, \mathrm d\lambda
\approx
\int \frac{(pf)^2}{q}\, \mathrm d\lambda - \int \frac{(pf)^2}{q^2}\, h\, \mathrm d\lambda
=
\Phi(q) + \Big\langle -\frac{(pf)^2}{q^2}\, ,\,  h \Big\rangle_{L^2(\lambda)}
$$
Since we are considering the best linear approximation, the linear map
$$
A\colon h\mapsto \Big\langle -\frac{(pf)^2}{q^2}\, ,\,  h \Big\rangle_{L^2(\lambda)}
$$
fulfills the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) property:
$$
\frac{\left|\Phi(q+h)-\Phi(q)-Ah\right|}{\left\|h\right\|}\xrightarrow{h\to 0} 0.
$$
(Note that in your equation (1) you are adding real numbers and functions, which can not be correct - you really need to define the linear map $h\mapsto Ah$ in a proper way).

You obviously need to fill in some blanks to make this rigorous, in particular which spaces you are working in ($L^1$ or $L^2$). You should also verify that your map $\Phi$ is well-defined, meaning that the integral exists for $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$ and any $q$. I hope this helps..