# Minimize $q\mapsto\int\frac{(pf)^2}q\:{\rm d}\lambda$ subject to $\int q\:{\rm }\lambda=1$ using the method of Lagrange multipliers

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, optimization, lp-spaces, lagrange-multiplier

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda=1$$
- $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$

> I want to minimize $$\Phi(q):=\int_{\left\{\:q\:>\:0\:\right\}}\frac{(pf)^2}q\:{\rm d}\lambda$$ over all $\mathcal E$-measurable $q:E\to[0,\infty)$ subject to $$\int q\:{\rm d}\lambda=1.\tag1$$ I already know that the solution is proportional to $p|f|$, but I want to verify this rigorously.
>
> I want to use he method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). We should be able to rephrase the problem in the following way: We want to minimize a functional on a Banach space subject to the condition that the norm of the candidate is $1$. We would clearly take the Banach space $\mathcal L^1(\mu)$ (note that $(1)$ is noting else than the norm of $q$ in this space).
>
> How do we need to proceed in detail?

It's clear to me that it's sufficient to find a stationary point of the Lagrange function. It's then easy to show that the resulting candidate solution is a minimum (using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality).

Please take note of my related question: [How can we compute the Fréchet derivative of $q\mapsto\int\frac{(pf)^2}q\:{\rm d}\lambda$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3313467/47771).

Comment: The solution is usually _not_ proportional to $|p(x)f(x)|$ for all $x \in E$.  In fact the situation usually degenerates to an infimum of 0 that cannot be achieved (see below).

Comment: You can solve with a (typically) non-degenerate solution if you add some additional assumptions, such as the constraint that $q(x)>0$ whenever $p(x)f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Michael Actually, I want that $\{pf\ne0\}\subseteq\{q>0\}$, but I didn't know how I can incorporate this constraint into the problem. I hoped that the minimizer of the problem as stated could be shown to satisfy this property. Since this is not the case, how can we incorporate this constraint and solve the problem?

Comment: I have added another answer that gives a problem with solution proportional to $|p(x)f(x)|$.

Comment: @Michael First of all, thank you very much for the tremendous effort you already spent to answer my question. Actually, I already knew how I can prove that the $q$ you've defined in your second answer is the minimizer. But this proof relies on that we already have the right guess for the minimizer at hand. So, what I really want to know how we come up with the solution (under the additional constraint $\{pf\ne0\}\subseteq\{q>0\}$) using Lagrange multipliers. (I'm interested in this, since I want to understand how I can use this machinery in more complex situations.)

Comment: @Michael The idea should be to use Lagrange multipliers to find an extreme value of the Lagrangian function and then show that it is the minimum we're searching for by the reasoning you've laid out in your second answer.

Comment: @Michael Would be great if you could elaborate on that.

Comment: In my second answer, the $c^2$ value is the Lagrange multiplier: I give details in a new comment in the second answer.

Comment: @Michael Thank you very much for your comment. I've asked for my concrete problem in an other question on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/338619/91890. It would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: @Michael (I don't know if you've already taken a look at the question on mathoverflow, but please note that I've edited that question. I think I've reduced the problem description significantly.)

Comment: I cannot follow the description on that link.

Comment: @Michael Is it because you're not familiar with the topic or is something unclear?

Comment: Way too jargony.  I observe, for example, that $\mu$ is introduced and then never used. I suspect lots of things could be simplified.  The Markov chain takes us by surprise at the yellow block, since there was no mention of it before.  Not clear what is going on.

Comment: @Michael Give me one last shot: The following problem should be quite similar to the one I've asked in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3338883/47771. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a problem that can be solved with solution proportional to $|p(x)f(x)|$.

#### Problem

Given:

- $(E, \mathcal{E}, \lambda)$
- Measurable functions $p:E\rightarrow [0,\infty)$, $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
- $\int_E p(x)d\lambda = 1$
- $0< \int_E |f(x)p(x)|d\lambda < \infty$.
- $p(x)f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x \in E$.

We want to find a measurable function $q:E\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ to minimize $\int_E \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)}d\lambda $ subject to:

1. $\int_E q(x)d\lambda = 1$
2. $q(x)>0$ for all $x \in E$.

#### Minimizer

Define the measurable function $q:E\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ by
$$ q(x) = \frac{1}{c}|p(x)f(x)| \quad \forall x \in E  $$
where $c$ is defined
$$ c = \int_E |p(x)f(x)|d\lambda $$

Clearly this function $q(x)$ satisfies the desired constraints 1 and 2. It remains to prove it minimizes the objective over all other measurable functions $r:E\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ that satisfy constraints 1 and 2.

#### Optimality proof

Fix a measurable function $r:E\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ that satisfies constraints 1 and 2, so that $\int_E r(x)dx = 1$ and $r(x)>0$ for all $x \in E$. Fix $x \in E$.  Note that $q(x)$ defined above is chosen as the value $q \in (0,\infty)$ that minimizes the expression
$$  \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{q} + c^2q $$ 
where this expression is convex in $q$ and has a unique minimizer in $(0,\infty)$ 
(recall that $(p(x)f(x))^2>0$). Since $r(x)>0$ we have 
$$  \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)} + c^2q(x) \leq \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{r(x)} + c^2r(x) \quad \forall x \in E$$
Integrating the above inequality gives
$$ \int_E \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)}d\lambda  + c^2 \underbrace{\int_E q(x)d\lambda}_{1} \leq \int_E \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{r(x)}d\lambda + c^2\underbrace{\int_E r(x)d\lambda}_{1}$$ 
where the underbrace equalities hold because both $q$ and $r$ satisfy constraint 1.  Canceling common terms yields
$$ \int_E \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)}d\lambda  \leq \int_E \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{r(x)}d\lambda$$
$\Box$

Comment: The $c^2$ value is the Lagrange multiplier, I arrived at this answer as follows: Fix $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, we want to minimize  $$ \int_E \frac{(g(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)}d\lambda  + \mu \int_E q(x)d\lambda$$ This is equivalent to minimizing $$\int_E\left[\frac{(g(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)} + \mu q(x)\right]d\lambda$$ so we minimize the integrand for each $x$ to get $q(x) = |f(x)p(x)|/\sqrt{\mu}$ (retroactively suppose $\mu>0$).  To ensure $\int_E q(x)d\lambda = 1$ we can choose $\mu = c^2$.

Comment: This method is the same as Theorem II.1 here: http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/network-optimization-notes.pdf  In the language of those notes, the set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is $$A = \left\{\left(\int_E q(x)d\lambda, \int_E \frac{(g(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)}d\lambda\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : q  \in C \right\}$$ where $C$ is the set of functions $q:E\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ that yield well defined and finite values of those two integrals. We want to minimize the second integral subject to $\int_E q(x)d\lambda \leq 1$. This constraint is met with equality for the minimizer $q^* \in C$.

Answer (score 4):

#### Counter-example

Here is a counter-example to show the solution will not necessarily be proportional to $|p(x)f(x)|$ over all $x \in E$, and the problem can have degenerate cases:

Define:

- $E=[0,1]$ with the usual Lebesgue measure.
- $p(x) = 1, f(x)=x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

For each $d \in (0,1]$ define

$$q_d(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{2x}{d^2} &\mbox{ if $x\in [0,d]$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Then $\int_0^1 q_d(x)dx = 1$ for all $d \in (0,1]$ and 
$$ \int_{x:q(x)>0} \frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{q(x)}dx = \frac{d^2}{2}\int_0^dx dx = \frac{d^4}{4}$$

Now the function $q_1(x)$ is proportional to $|p(x)f(x)|$ over all $x \in [0,1]$, but this has objective function $\frac{d^4}{4}|_{d=1}= 1/4$.  We can do better by pushing $d\rightarrow 0$ to get an infimum objective value of $0$. This is a degenerate case when there is no minimizer but we can find a sequence of functions that satisfy the constraints and that have objective values that converge to the infimum of 0.

---

#### General case

You can repeat the example to solve almost all general cases this way: 
Fix $(E,\mathcal{E}, \lambda)$ and fix $p:E\rightarrow [0,\infty)$, $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that for all positive integers $n$ there is a measurable set $B_n \subseteq E$ such that 
$$ 0<\int_{B_n} |p(x)f(x)|d\lambda \leq 1/n$$
Define 
$$c_n = \int_{B_n} |p(x)f(x)|d\lambda \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ..\}$$
and note that $0<c_n\leq 1/n$. For each $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ define $q_n:E\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by
$$ q_n(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{|p(x)f(x)|}{c_n} &\mbox{ if $x\in B_n$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Then $\int q_n(x)d\lambda = \frac{1}{c_n}\int_{B_n} |p(x)f(x)|d\lambda=1$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ but
$$ \int_{x:q_n(x)>0}\frac{(p(x)f(x))^2}{q_n(x)} d\lambda = c_n\int_{B_n}|p(x)f(x)|d\lambda = c_n^2\rightarrow 0$$
So the infimum objective value is 0.

If we assume that $\lambda(\{x \in E : p(x)f(x)=0\}) = 0$ then it can be shown that it is impossible to achieve an objective value of 0. Thus, this situation is degenerate: There is no minimizer, but there is an infinite sequence of functions that satisfy the constraints and that have objective function that converges to the infimum of 0.

On the other hand, if we can find a measurable set $B\subseteq E$ such that $0<\lambda(B) < \infty$ and $p(x)f(x)=0$ for all $x \in B$, then we can easily achieve the optimal objective value of $0$ with
$$ q(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{\lambda(B)} &\mbox{ if $x \in B$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: The property stated for the general case is mild: For example, suppose $E= \mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual Lebesgue measure. Case 1: If $0<\int |p(x)f(x)|dx <\infty$, then indeed for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ there is a set $B_n$ such that $$0<\int_{B_n} |p(x)f(x)|dx \leq 1/n$$ and so the infimum is 0. Case 2: If $\int |p(x)f(x)|dx =0$ then there is a set $B$ such that $0<\lambda(B)<\infty$ and so the infimum is also 0 (and is achievable).